# Rails helper doesn't have access to base class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I've got helper which I'm including inside `Create` service class. This `Create` service inherits from Base class and I'm including `::Imports::HashFieldsBuilder` to have access to its `size_fields` method - like below:

Base class:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Products
  class Base
    def with_retry(limit: 3, wait: 2, &block)
      block.call
    rescue Imports::Client::BadGatewayError => e
      attempt ||= 0
      attempt += 1
      sleep(wait) and retry if attempt < limit
      raise e
    end

    def client
      @client ||= Imports::Client.new
    end
  end
end
```

Create class:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Products
  class Create < Base
    include ::Imports::HashFieldsBuilder

    def initialize(product:)
      @product = product
    end

    def call
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        size_fields(product)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Helper which is included inside Create service:

```
module Imports::HashFieldsBuilder
  extend self

  def size_fields(product)
    with_retry { client.product_size_specs(product_id: product['_id']) }
  end
end
```

This code produces me an error:

> NoMethodError:
> undefined method `with_retry' for Imports::HashFieldsBuilder:Module

Which means that `::Imports::HashFieldsBuilder` doesn't have access `Base` class methods: `with_retry` and `client`. But why? I have already included this helper to the `Client` class, which inherits from the Base class.

Comment: The error suggests that `with_retry` is being called on the module itself, `Imports::HashFieldsBuilder`. At a glance, with the code provided, it shouldn't be happening. Something else must be wrong, in the code you're not showing.

Comment: Nah, if I add `with_retry` method into helper everything works well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SiimLiiser if this is not the minimal-reproducible example I don't know what is

Comment: I would like to help you, but I cannot, because I cannot reproduce your error. I don't know what is `Imports::Client::BadGatewayError`, what is any of `client.product_size_specs(product_id: product['_id'])` and so on. It's not complete. Those parts are probably not relevant to the error you're getting though, so it's also not minimal. I tried removing all the parts that you did not provide code for, but then everything works as it's supposed to, so it's also not reproducible. Please provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example so we could actually help you.